# IntelliJ style problems after crashing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

[IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) crashed for me, and in doing so it lost all of my files. They where still in the project folder itself and in git, but within the project window they where gone. I re-installed IntelliJ, and now there are several style issues.

The first is that used code is being marked as unused, and the second is that the colors for the styles are not being displayed either. This is with the new Scala plugin as well (3.0.3). I have already tried clearing the cache to no avail.  [image]

EDIT: Throw into the mix IntelliJ isn't compiling either so Im unable to even go to definition anywhere now.

Comment: Do the Platform Settings of your Project (File-> Project Structure -> Platform Settings) have a JDK associciated for java and an sdk for scala?

Comment: @Zee it does have a jdk and an sdk as well, it did prompt me to add those and I did.

Comment: Im assuming you've also already tried shutting intellij down entirely and restarting it?

Comment: @Zee multiple times, I've noticed that I had to have activator clear my files to get it compile as well. After it did though, intelli j is still not compiling either.

Comment: Im running intellij on linux so i see its error output, do you see any exceptions being thrown? Also what version of intellij are you using specifically

Comment: have you tried to clean intellij files (like `.idea`) and importing again?

Comment: @pedrorijo91 That actually fixed my problem, the re-importing the project again.

Comment: @TheM00s3 nice :) it happened to me once, seems the file gets corrupted

Comment: @pedrorijo91That does seem to be the case, hence the crash I was describing earlier.

Answer (score 0):

When I see this sort of problem in Intellij, I first try "Refresh all SBT projects."  Before I discovered where that was, I used to add a blank to build.sbt and then opt to Refresh at the prompt that popped up.  Something similar exists for Maven projects, but I don't have experience with those.  In more extreme situations, deleting the project and reimporting use "Import Project" has worked.